# Adding ‘company’ to a customer using portable.licensing in C#

Tags: c#, licensing

I am currently building licenses using the following Portable.Licensing (https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing) code:

```
var license = Portable.Licensing.License.New();
license.WithUniqueIdentifier(guid);
license.As(Portable.Licensing.LicenseType.Standard);
license.LicensedTo(textBox_LicenseName.Text, textBox_LicenseEmail.Text);
```

There is an alternative definition for the function LicensedTo() that takes an additional argument:

```
LicensedTo(string name, string email, Action<Customer> configureCustomer);
```

How do I go about using this additional argument to include the 'Company Name' along with the Name and Email?

Comment: You have asked this already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53081722/how-do-i-add-company-to-portable-licensing-customer

Comment: mentioning https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing could also help.

Comment: I did ask the question before but it was put hold for not having enough information and was then stuck on hold even after editing, so I’ve re-asked the question with the new wording.

Comment: Falco, good idea. I did refer to it in the title but I’ve added the link in to the post body now as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `WithAdditionalAttributes` for that:

```
var license = License.New()
    .WithUniqueIdentifier(Guid.NewGuid())

    //Look here
    .WithAdditionalAttributes(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"CompanyName", companyName }
    })

    .As(LicenseType.Trial)
    .ExpiresAt(DateTime.Now.AddDays(30))
    .WithMaximumUtilization(numberOfUsers)
    .LicensedTo(licensedTo, contactEmail)
    .CreateAndSignWithPrivateKey(privateKey, passPhrase);
```

And to retrieve it from the generated license:

```
var fs = new FileStream("license.lic", FileMode.Open);
var license = License.Load(fs);
var name = license.AdditionalAttributes.Get("CompanyName");
fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method

```
var license = Portable.Licensing.License.New();
license.WithUniqueIdentifier(guid);
license.As(Portable.Licensing.LicenseType.Standard);
license.LicensedTo((c) => { c.Name = textBox_LicenseName.Text; c.Email = textBox_LicenseEmail.Text; c.Company = textBox_CompanyName.Text; });
```